# Can I declare a variable inside a statement?

Tags: java

I'm having programming lessons in school but i'm already "advanced" (I can do the exercises easily), so I was bored and I wanted to make the full program in 1 line.
I could do it in 2 (being 1 line only a declaration).
So I was thinking if I can somehow make it in 1 line. Any one have an ideia?

Here is the code:

```
int i;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ((i = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in your result")))) >= 6) ? "Approved" : ((i < 4) ? "Final test" : "Reproved"));
```

PS. I'm using java, but if you have the answer in C or C++ it will work too!

PS 2. I don't want to create a method, class or anything like that, I want a single line of code that if in "main" method it will work (imports are allowed).

This is just a challenge from my friends that I couldn't do, not my programming style or anything like that...

Thanks!

Comment: I said it could be in C/C++ ...

Comment: You misunderstand what "advanced" means... In particular it does not mean being able to write the most obscure code that nobody will understand (that goal is actually fairly easy to achieve)...

Comment: Sorry, What i was trying to say with "advanced", is that I could do all exercises easily, and I wanted a challenge (a friend proposed it)...

Comment: In C/C++ you can use the comma operator, like `f(),g(),h(),...` to evaluate all expressions, discard all results, and the set the final result of the statement as the result of the last expression. This way you can basically evaluate a whole bunch of functions. You cannot however combine this with variable declaration. I am not sure about Java though.

Comment: Are you referring to the C language or the C++ language?  They are different.  Decide.

Comment: This is bad coding style, even for Java.

Comment: There's no problem doing it one line, because Java doesn't care about whitespace. Presumably you want to code it in one statement. What exactly that means is still a little unclear.

Comment: @shmosel I interpreted it as: only one semicolon.

Comment: I know this is a bad coding style, as I said, this i just a challenge that I coudn't do.
Yes Zanyo, only one semicolon, that's what i was trying to say!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go - some garbage code with Java 8 syntax that probably does what you wanted:

```
IntStream.of(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in your result")))
        .mapToObj(i -> i >= 6 ? "Approved" : (i < 4 ? "Final test" : "Reproved"))
        .forEach(s -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s));
```

Comment: Exorcizo te, omnis spiritus immunde, in nomine Dei Patris omnipotentis, et in nomine Jesu Christi Filii ejus, Domini et Judicis nostri, et in virtute Spiritus Sancti...This is absolutely brilliant, and complete garbage! +1.

Comment: Thanks! I don't have the java 8 installed yet so I can't test it, but I'll download it and test!

Answer (score 2):

The only way you could do this, but is super ugly, is use the switch statement which is the only statement which will capture the parse and you can then have multiple cases for your values ( with empty fall throughs)

Comment: I know, but you wouldn't do those,  you'd do case:0 case:1: case 2: up to 6

Comment: @KeithNicholas What if I just type in -666? It's a *signed integer*.

Comment: Can you show me with a code example what you mean by "switch capturing the parse"?

Comment: Zan, Math.min and Math.max to constrain thevalue

Comment: @pbabcdefp `switch(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in your result")){case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final test"); break; case 4: case 5:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final test"); break; default:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Approved");}`   not that I can compile Java at the moment, but something like that

Comment: That's actually pretty clever, didn't think of using cases for Math.min. I think this is a good answer; even though it didn't answer the title question exactly it solves the OPs problem, basically.

Comment: How about the user entering -1 ? or -1000 ?

Comment: Thank you for that example. Apart from one missing ) it does compile (+1).

Comment: Actually, I looked at this a second time, and I'm not sure what I was thinking. There's absolutely no way the bounds will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable in one statement:

```
int i;
```

That's it. What you are asking for just isn't possible, assuming you aren't referring to compound statements.

While you can technically *define* a variable in an expression, you shouldn't ever do so; it's awful programming style, and makes your code unreadable.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a very bad programming style! This is just a challange that my friends proposed me and I couldn't do it.

Comment: There are lots of statements which can contain declarations: conditional statements, loop statements, compound statements.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Declaration statements? :p

Comment: @KerrekSB I made the assumption that when he uses the term statement, he's not referring to any of those.

Comment: and one that's actually an expression: lambda

Comment: @keyser But you can't use a lambda if you don't have a defined variable on the outside to get its result. And as for doing the test in the lambda...well, it's turtles all the way down.

Comment: @Z̷͙̗̻͖̣̹͉̫̬̪̖̤͆ͤ̓ͫͭ̀̐͜͞ͅͅαлγo True, but what if it doesn't return anything? :) (I'm not saying it's applicable to OP's situation though)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some more garbage Java 8 code shamelessly ripped off from @assylias's answer.

```
Collections.singleton(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in your result")))
        .forEach(i -> {
            Collections.singleton(i >= 6 ? "Approved" : (i < 4 ? "Final test" : "Reproved"))
                    .forEach(s -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s));
        });
```